# How to Refresh/reload Select dropdown options

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu

I have 3 Dropdown menus linked to each other (Brand,Parameter,SubBrands). The third dropdown menu's ("Subbrands") options should be basis the option selected in the first menu (Brand).

The jquery for this part is as below:

```
jQuery("#Brand, #Parameter").on('change', function () {
    jQuery("#SubBrands").val(null).trigger('change');
      if ($("#Brand").val() == 'Brand1' && $("#Parameter").val() == 'ShowBrands') {
        jQuery ('#SubBrands option').filter('option[value="SubBrand1Hide"]').hide();
      }
      if ($("#Brand").val() == 'Brand2' && $("#Parameter").val() == 'ShowBrands') {
        jQuery ('#SubBrands option').filter('option[value="SubBrand2Hide"]').hide();
      }
      if ($("#Brand").val() == 'Brand3' && $("#Parameter").val() == 'ShowBrands') {
        jQuery ('#SubBrands option').filter('option[value="SubBrand3Hide"]').hide();
      }
      if ($("#Brand").val() == 'Brand4' && $("#Parameter").val() == 'ShowBrands') {
        jQuery ('#SubBrands option').filter('option[value="SubBrand4Hide"]').hide();
      }
      $("#SubBrands").val([]);
    });
```

While the respective 'SubBrands' are being hidden as required, when I change the main 'Brand' and relook at the 'SubBrand' dropdown, the previous hidden 'SubBrand' does not reappear. I need this menu to refresh everytime the main 'Brand' selection changes.

The whole working code is as below:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  jQuery("#Parameter").on('change', function() {
    if (this.value == "ShowBrands") {
      $("#SubBrandBox").show();
    } else {
      $("#SubBrandBox").hide();
    }
  });
  jQuery("#Brand, #Parameter").on('change', function() {
    jQuery("#SubBrands").val(null).trigger('change');
    if ($("#Brand").val() == 'Brand1' && $("#Parameter").val() == 'ShowBrands') {
      jQuery('#SubBrands option').filter('option[value="SubBrand1Hide"]').hide();
    }
    if ($("#Brand").val() == 'Brand2' && $("#Parameter").val() == 'ShowBrands') {
      jQuery('#SubBrands option').filter('option[value="SubBrand2Hide"]').hide();
    }
    if ($("#Brand").val() == 'Brand3' && $("#Parameter").val() == 'ShowBrands') {
      jQuery('#SubBrands option').filter('option[value="SubBrand3Hide"]').hide();
    }
    if ($("#Brand").val() == 'Brand4' && $("#Parameter").val() == 'ShowBrands') {
      jQuery('#SubBrands option').filter('option[value="SubBrand4Hide"]').hide();
    }
    $("#SubBrands").val([]);
  });

});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}

</style></head><body>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  Which Brand:
  <select id="Brand">
    <option></option>
    <option value="Brand1">Brand1</option>
    <option value="Brand2">Brand2</option>
    <option value="Brand3">Brand3</option>
    <option value="Brand4">Brand4</option>
  </select>
  </br>
  Parameter
  <select id="Parameter">
    <option></option>
    <option value="ShowBrands">Show Sub-Brands</option>
    <option value="HideBrands">Hide Sub-Brands</option>
  </select>
  </br>
  <div id="SubBrandBox" style="display: none;">
    Sub-Brands
    <select id="SubBrands">
      <option></option>
      <option value="SubBrand1Hide">AAAA</option>
      <option value="SubBrand2Hide">BBBB</option>
      <option value="SubBrand3Hide">CCCC</option>
      <option value="SubBrand4Hide">DDDD</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi Mithun, I was just wondering, if you even get a chance to look at my idea? See the other answer and tell me what you feel?  A simple appreciation or a feedback gives me more strength. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show all options first then hide the specific one:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  jQuery("#Parameter").on('change', function() {
    if (this.value == "ShowBrands") {
      $("#SubBrandBox").show();
    } else {
      $("#SubBrandBox").hide();
    }
  });
  jQuery("#Brand, #Parameter").on('change', function() {
    jQuery("#SubBrands").val(null).trigger('change');
    
    // Show all options here
    jQuery('#SubBrands option').show();
    
    if ($("#Brand").val() == 'Brand1' && $("#Parameter").val() == 'ShowBrands') {
      jQuery('#SubBrands option').filter('option[value="SubBrand1Hide"]').hide();
    }
    if ($("#Brand").val() == 'Brand2' && $("#Parameter").val() == 'ShowBrands') {
      jQuery('#SubBrands option').filter('option[value="SubBrand2Hide"]').hide();
    }
    if ($("#Brand").val() == 'Brand3' && $("#Parameter").val() == 'ShowBrands') {
      jQuery('#SubBrands option').filter('option[value="SubBrand3Hide"]').hide();
    }
    if ($("#Brand").val() == 'Brand4' && $("#Parameter").val() == 'ShowBrands') {
      jQuery('#SubBrands option').filter('option[value="SubBrand4Hide"]').hide();
    }
    $("#SubBrands").val([]);
  });

});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  Which Brand:
  <select id="Brand">
    <option></option>
    <option value="Brand1">Brand1</option>
    <option value="Brand2">Brand2</option>
    <option value="Brand3">Brand3</option>
    <option value="Brand4">Brand4</option>
  </select>
  </br>
  Parameter
  <select id="Parameter">
    <option></option>
    <option value="ShowBrands">Show Sub-Brands</option>
    <option value="HideBrands">Hide Sub-Brands</option>
  </select>
  </br>
  <div id="SubBrandBox" style="display: none;">
    Sub-Brands
    <select id="SubBrands">
      <option></option>
      <option value="SubBrand1Hide">AAAA</option>
      <option value="SubBrand2Hide">BBBB</option>
      <option value="SubBrand3Hide">CCCC</option>
      <option value="SubBrand4Hide">DDDD</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</body>
```

And the below snippet is some refactor I made. It shorten your condition:

```
jQuery('#SubBrands option').show();
if ($("#Parameter").val() == 'ShowBrands') {
  let branch = $("#Brand").val();
  jQuery('#SubBrands option').filter(`option[value="Sub${branch}Hide"]`).hide()
}
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  jQuery("#Parameter").on('change', function() {
    if (this.value == "ShowBrands") {
      $("#SubBrandBox").show();
    } else {
      $("#SubBrandBox").hide();
    }
  });
  jQuery("#Brand, #Parameter").on('change', function() {
    jQuery("#SubBrands").val(null).trigger('change');
    
    jQuery('#SubBrands option').show();
    if ($("#Parameter").val() == 'ShowBrands') {
      let branch = $("#Brand").val();
      jQuery('#SubBrands option').filter(`option[value="Sub${branch}Hide"]`).hide()
    }
    
    $("#SubBrands").val([]);
  });

});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  Which Brand:
  <select id="Brand">
    <option></option>
    <option value="Brand1">Brand1</option>
    <option value="Brand2">Brand2</option>
    <option value="Brand3">Brand3</option>
    <option value="Brand4">Brand4</option>
  </select>
  </br>
  Parameter
  <select id="Parameter">
    <option></option>
    <option value="ShowBrands">Show Sub-Brands</option>
    <option value="HideBrands">Hide Sub-Brands</option>
  </select>
  </br>
  <div id="SubBrandBox" style="display: none;">
    Sub-Brands
    <select id="SubBrands">
      <option></option>
      <option value="SubBrand1Hide">AAAA</option>
      <option value="SubBrand2Hide">BBBB</option>
      <option value="SubBrand3Hide">CCCC</option>
      <option value="SubBrand4Hide">DDDD</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're better off having a filter button or something. I'd say a Hide or Show button along with this. Keep an object or something that tracks everything.

Your second `<select>` should be an action select. This needs to get updated or show the current source of truth. See the below example:

```js
var config = {
  "brand-A": "hide",
  "brand-B": "hide",
  "brand-C": "hide"
};
$(function () {
  $("#brand").change(function () {
    $("#show").val(config[$(this).val()]).prop("disabled", false);
  });
  $("#show").change(function () {
    $brand = $("#brand").val();
    config[$brand] = $(this).val();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Choose a brand:
<select id="brand">
  <option value="" disabled selected></option>
  <option value="brand-A">Brand A</option>
  <option value="brand-B">Brand B</option>
  <option value="brand-C">Brand C</option>
</select>
<br />
Show or Hide:
<select id="show" disabled="disabled">
  <option value="" disabled selected></option>
  <option value="show">Show</option>
  <option value="hide">Hide</option>
</select>
```

Here we have got a connected component right now with a mini-config. Now based on this change - we need to show or hide the products:

```js
var config = {
  "brand-A": "show",
  "brand-B": "hide",
  "brand-C": "hide"
};
```

Now coming to the show action, we write this way:

```js
var config = {
  "brand-A": "hide",
  "brand-B": "hide",
  "brand-C": "hide"
};
$(function () {
  $("#brand").change(function () {
    $("#show").val(config[$(this).val()]).prop("disabled", false);
  });
  $("#show").change(function () {
    $brand = $("#brand").val();
    config[$brand] = $(this).val();
    // Hide all the products:
    $("#products option").not(":first").prop("hidden", true);
    $("#products option.brand-A").prop("hidden", config["brand-A"] === "hide");
    $("#products option.brand-B").prop("hidden", config["brand-B"] === "hide");
    $("#products option.brand-C").prop("hidden", config["brand-C"] === "hide");
  });
});
```

This gives us with what you need:

```js
var config = {
  "brand-A": "hide",
  "brand-B": "hide",
  "brand-C": "hide"
};
$(function () {
  $("#brand").change(function () {
    $("#show").val(config[$(this).val()]).prop("disabled", false);
  });
  $("#show").change(function () {
    $brand = $("#brand").val();
    config[$brand] = $(this).val();
    // Hide all the products:
    $("#products option").not(":first").prop("hidden", true);
    $("#products option.brand-A").prop("hidden", config["brand-A"] === "hide");
    $("#products option.brand-B").prop("hidden", config["brand-B"] === "hide");
    $("#products option.brand-C").prop("hidden", config["brand-C"] === "hide");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
Choose a brand:
<select id="brand">
  <option value="" disabled selected></option>
  <option value="brand-A">Brand A</option>
  <option value="brand-B">Brand B</option>
  <option value="brand-C">Brand C</option>
</select>
<br />
Show or Hide:
<select id="show" disabled="disabled">
  <option value="" disabled selected></option>
  <option value="show">Show</option>
  <option value="hide">Hide</option>
</select>
<br />
List of Products:
<select id="products">
  <option value="" disabled selected></option>
  <option hidden="hidden" class="brand-A" value="product-A-1">Product A-1</option>
  <option hidden="hidden" class="brand-A" value="product-A-2">Product A-2</option>
  <option hidden="hidden" class="brand-A" value="product-A-3">Product A-3</option>
  <option hidden="hidden" class="brand-B" value="product-B-1">Product B-1</option>
  <option hidden="hidden" class="brand-B" value="product-B-2">Product B-2</option>
  <option hidden="hidden" class="brand-B" value="product-B-3">Product B-3</option>
  <option hidden="hidden" class="brand-C" value="product-C-1">Product C-1</option>
  <option hidden="hidden" class="brand-C" value="product-C-2">Product C-2</option>
  <option hidden="hidden" class="brand-C" value="product-C-3">Product C-3</option>
</select>
<p hidden="hidden">You have selected <strong></strong></p>
```

You can also make this in a better way, by using the `Object.keys`, replacing the following:

```
$("#products option.brand-A").prop("hidden", config["brand-A"] === "hide");
$("#products option.brand-B").prop("hidden", config["brand-B"] === "hide");
$("#products option.brand-C").prop("hidden", config["brand-C"] === "hide");
```

with this:

```
Object.keys(config).forEach(function (br) {
  $("#products option." + br).prop("hidden", config[br] === "hide");
});
```

Here's your final snippet:

```js
var config = {
  "brand-A": "hide",
  "brand-B": "hide",
  "brand-C": "hide"
};
$(function () {
  $("#brand").change(function () {
    $("#show").val(config[$(this).val()]).prop("disabled", false);
  });
  $("#show").change(function () {
    $brand = $("#brand").val();
    config[$brand] = $(this).val();
    // Hide all the products:
    $("#products option").not(":first").prop("hidden", true);
    Object.keys(config).forEach(function (br) {
      $("#products option." + br).prop("hidden", config[br] === "hide");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
Choose a brand:
<select id="brand">
  <option value="" disabled selected></option>
  <option value="brand-A">Brand A</option>
  <option value="brand-B">Brand B</option>
  <option value="brand-C">Brand C</option>
</select>
<br />
Show or Hide:
<select id="show" disabled="disabled">
  <option value="" disabled selected></option>
  <option value="show">Show</option>
  <option value="hide">Hide</option>
</select>
<br />
List of Products:
<select id="products">
  <option value="" disabled selected></option>
  <option hidden="hidden" class="brand-A" value="product-A-1">Product A-1</option>
  <option hidden="hidden" class="brand-A" value="product-A-2">Product A-2</option>
  <option hidden="hidden" class="brand-A" value="product-A-3">Product A-3</option>
  <option hidden="hidden" class="brand-B" value="product-B-1">Product B-1</option>
  <option hidden="hidden" class="brand-B" value="product-B-2">Product B-2</option>
  <option hidden="hidden" class="brand-B" value="product-B-3">Product B-3</option>
  <option hidden="hidden" class="brand-C" value="product-C-1">Product C-1</option>
  <option hidden="hidden" class="brand-C" value="product-C-2">Product C-2</option>
  <option hidden="hidden" class="brand-C" value="product-C-3">Product C-3</option>
</select>
<p hidden="hidden">You have selected <strong></strong></p>
```

Another representation:

```js
var config = {
  "brand-A": "hide",
  "brand-B": "hide",
  "brand-C": "hide"
};
$(function () {
  $("#brand").change(function () {
    $("#show").val(config[$(this).val()]).prop("disabled", false);
  });
  $("#show").change(function () {
    $brand = $("#brand").val();
    config[$brand] = $(this).val();
    // Hide all the products:
    $("#products option").not(":first").prop("hidden", true);
    Object.keys(config).forEach(function (br) {
      $("#products option." + br).prop("hidden", config[br] === "hide");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
Choose a brand:
<select id="brand">
  <option value="" disabled selected></option>
  <option value="brand-A">Brand A</option>
  <option value="brand-B">Brand B</option>
  <option value="brand-C">Brand C</option>
</select>
<br />
Show or Hide:
<select id="show" disabled="disabled">
  <option value="" disabled selected></option>
  <option value="show">Show</option>
  <option value="hide">Hide</option>
</select>
<br />
List of Products:
<select id="products" size="10" style="width: 100px;">
  <option value="" disabled selected></option>
  <option hidden="hidden" class="brand-A" value="product-A-1">Product A-1</option>
  <option hidden="hidden" class="brand-A" value="product-A-2">Product A-2</option>
  <option hidden="hidden" class="brand-A" value="product-A-3">Product A-3</option>
  <option hidden="hidden" class="brand-B" value="product-B-1">Product B-1</option>
  <option hidden="hidden" class="brand-B" value="product-B-2">Product B-2</option>
  <option hidden="hidden" class="brand-B" value="product-B-3">Product B-3</option>
  <option hidden="hidden" class="brand-C" value="product-C-1">Product C-1</option>
  <option hidden="hidden" class="brand-C" value="product-C-2">Product C-2</option>
  <option hidden="hidden" class="brand-C" value="product-C-3">Product C-3</option>
</select>
<p hidden="hidden">You have selected <strong></strong></p>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Praveen. Thanks a lot for all the valuable inputs and effort you have taken into that amazing write-up!! Its very useful and will make for a very good reference even for future queries! :)

Comment: @MithunUchil Just curious, did I understand the question wrong, coz when I tried the answer above and your question, I couldn't understand how the selects should work. I get to see the same output in both. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi @Praveen. Yes, I meant to highlight that, but seeing the effort you have taken didnt feel like pointing it out. :). As mentioned in my question, I need the 'sub-brands' to refresh everytime I change the brand so that the previously hidden 'sub-brand' re-appears.  `jQuery('#SubBrands option').show();` before the 'hide()' commands does the job, as replied by  @Cuong Le Ngoc. But thanks again, as I am a newbie to coding and appreciate all inputs here. :)

Comment: @MithunUchil Just made a screencast of the same: https://i.imgur.com/3jOq0FU.mp4. Have a nice day. 